# Validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I have a account is TEST and i have a checkbox whenever user is try to check the checkbox for TEST account at that time validation rule have to be fire.remain all cases no validation rule will be fire.

Comment: I think this question needs a little more detailing.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your existing validation rule?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Validation rule with the formula

```
if(Name =='TEST' && checkbox__c, true, false ) // here checkbox__c is api name of your checkbox field
```

or we can also use this

```
Name =='TEST' && checkbox__c
```

But keep in mind that Test is conman name and use for testing purpose so you might get error in your test class and test records as well.

Comment: Couldn't that be re-written as just `Name == 'TEST' && checkbox__c`

Comment: @NickCook yes we can use this as well.